# Nltk: Eliminating stop words from list of list

Tags: python, list, pandas, nltk, stop-words

I am trying to remove stop words and tried the following:

```
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
tokenized = data['data_column'].apply(tokenizer.tokenize)
tokenized
```

Below output after tokenization

```
0    [ANOTHER,SAMPLE,AS,OUTPUT,MSG...
1    [A,SAMPLE,TEXT,FOR,ILLUSTRATION...
Name: data_column, dtype: object
```

I try to remove stop words using the below:

```
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
filtered_sentence = [w for w in tokenized if not w in stop_words]
filtered_sentence = []
 for w in tokenized:
    if w not in stop_words:
        filtered_sentence.append(w)
```

I get error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-272-d4a699384ffc> in <module>()
      2 stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
      3 
----> 4 filtered_sentence = [w for w in tokenized if not w in stop_words]
      5 
      6 filtered_sentence = []

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: tokenized is a series you cant look up like that . Instead you need apply to look up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `.apply()` to filter the list from a list in series, since the corpus holds lowercased words you need to use .lower() before searching i.e

```
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
filtered_sentence = tokenized.apply(lambda x : [w for w in x if w.lower() not in stop_words])
```

Sample run

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))

df = pd.DataFrame({'words': [['A','SAMPLE','AS','OUTPUT','MSG']]})
df['words'].apply(lambda x : [i for i in x if not i.lower() in stop])

0    [SAMPLE, OUTPUT, MSG]
Name: words, dtype: object
```

Comment: Tried the code, `filtered_sentence`returns the same elements as `tokenized` again

Comment: No, but the goal is to remove the stop words from `tokenized`

Comment: As in the sample run, it does not convert it to lower case in the output